# set connect_timeout of elasticsearch php client

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, guzzle

i want to configure a a small timeout between my elasticsearch php client to the my elasticsearch server.

i tried to pass some parameters to the guzzle client but it seems this doesn't work.
here is the code:

```
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = $hosts;
$params['guzzleOptions']['connect_timeout'] = 2.0;
$params['guzzleOptions']['timeout'] = 2.0;
$this->elastica_obj = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```

i searched and found that the problem might occured because the timeout is set in the cURL layer (that is lower than the guzzle)
([Limit connecting time with Guzzle HTTP PHP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847633/limit-connecting-time-with-guzzle-http-php-client))

i guess i need somehow to set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS parameter to the value i want (2000ms) but i don't see any good way to pass it through the elasticsearch php client.

Does someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Zack,
I tried it but it doesn't work.

I debugged the client and the way the parameters are being pass from through the guzzle to the curl handle.

the way i find to accomplish it is to pass this parameter to the Elasticsearch client

```
$params['guzzleOptions']['curl.options'][CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 2.0;  // this applies 2 seconds connection_timeout
```

hope it is helping :)

Niv

Answer (score 9):

Since `elasticsearch/elasticsearch` v5.1.2, you also can use `setConnectionParams()` method which applies to all requests

```
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setConnectionParams([
        'client' => [
            RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => 10,
            RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        ],
    ])
    ->build();
```

Answer (score 3):

For the latest version 2.x it's done in a different way. Citing [Zach](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/259#issuecomment-164460926):

In ES-PHP 2.x the timeout is now specified per-request. See the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_per_request_configuration.html#_curl_timeouts

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'test',
    'type' => 'test',
    'id' => 1,
    'client' => [
        'timeout' => 10,        // ten second timeout
        'connect_timeout' => 10
    ]
];
$response = $client->get($params);
```

Though, it is not possible to do it on global level. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/382) for updates.

Comment: Updated link to the documentaiton: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/7.x/per_request_configuration.html#_curl_timeouts

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the 8.x Elasticsearch client, and I had to manually set the HTTP client to work around https://stackoverflow.com/a/71754458/1475468.

For me, setting the timeout values in the Guzzle HTTP client was the answer.

```php
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'connect_timeout' => 10, // seconds
        'timeout' => 10 // https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html
    ])) 
    ->setHosts(config('elasticsearch.hosts'))
    ->setApiKey(config('elasticsearch.api_key'))
    ->build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Elasticsearch-PHP client (and not Elastica):

The `guzzleOptions` parameter accepts any Guzzle parameter, and follows the same array syntax that Guzzle uses.  So you need to do:

```
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = $hosts;
$params['guzzleOptions']['command.request_options']['connect_timeout'] = 2.0;
$params['guzzleOptions']['command.request_options']['timeout'] = 2.0;
$this->elastica_obj = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```

This will apply a 2s timeout to all requests sent through the client

There is a "shortcut" `timeout` parameter that is supposed to apply to all connection types (Guzzle, CurlMultiConnection, etc)...but I'm looking through the code now and I dont think it actually works for Guzzle.  I'll open a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

In my php elastic version solution is

```
retun ClientBuilder::create()
      ->setHttpClientOptions([
            'connect_timeout' => 10,//seconds
        ])
       ->build();
```

Maybe someone will be useful =)