# How to set a proxy in official Elasticsearch PHP client?

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, guzzle

I know you can do it using the [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) client like so:

```
$client = new \Elastica\Client(array(
    'host' => 'my host',
    'port' => '9200',
    'proxy' => 'my proxy'
));
```

but I'd like to use the official client if possible.
I've set up a connection according to the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html).

```
$hosts = [
    [
    'host' => 'my host',
    'port' => '9200',
    'scheme' => 'http',
    'user' => 'my user',
    'pass' => 'my pass'
    ]
];
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
   ->setHosts($hosts)
   ->build();
```

However, there's nothing in the documentation on how to set a proxy.  Is it possible?

BTW, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491110/set-connect-timeout-of-elasticsearch-php-client), however it's outdated and doesn't work with the current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a cleaner syntax, but setting cURL parameters should work:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
   ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->setConnectionParams([
        'client' => [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy
            ]
        ]
    ])
   ->build();
```

Comment: That worked! Just a note though, if you also need to set the proxy port, use:

`'curl' => [
    CURLOPT_PROXY => "proxy",
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => "port"
]`