# Client is not supported for custom options

Tags: php, symfony6

I am trying to use `ClientBuilder` of Elasticsearch using symfony 6. I am getting following error

```
The HTTP client Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client is not supported for custom options
```

This is the code I have tried. I had same lines of code in laravel which worked.

```
$hosts = ['https://localhost:9200'];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->setSSLVerification(false)
    ->setBasicAuthentication('elastic', 'password')
    ->build();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue in a Laravel 9 app (along with some other bugs in the package).

Be sure to set the client manually, otherwise it uses `\Http\Discovery\Psr18ClientDiscovery` to find the first class that extends the required interface `\Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface`. Which in our case is `Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Psr18Client`, which is not yet supported (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/990).

```php
$hosts = ['https://localhost:9200'];

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client)
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->setSSLVerification(false)
    ->setBasicAuthentication('elastic', 'password')
    ->build();
```

Comment: How to set the ClientBuilder::create manually?

Comment: `$clientBuilder` is identical to `ClientBuilder::create()`. Edited my answer, can't reply properly here.

Comment: If you get a CURL SSL self signed error, add: `new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'verify' => false,
]`